# jQuery - How to run an .animate while the mouse travels a timeline?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, offset, timeline

I would like the div to run this animation while the mouse travels on the timeline. The div starts with `width/height 100px` when the mouse approaching the half of timeline, the div been resized simultaneously to `width/height 200px`. and when the mouse gets closer to the end of the timeline returns to div `width/height 100px`.

```
$('#timeline').mousemove(function(e){
    var position = e.clientX;
    $('#mark').css("left", position - 50);
});


$('#animation').animate({
    width: "200",
    height: "200"
}, 2000).animate({
    width: 100,
    height: 100
}, 2000);
```

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/69eEL/420/)

Please suggest.

Comment: Do you want the square to get bigger in proportion to your position along the time line, or just trigger the animation when you cross a certain threshold?

Comment: get bigger AND get smaller in proportion. the complete animation is get bigger to 200px, thrn get smaller to 100px. so, when the marker is half the timeline, will be the moment when he will reach 200px, and as we are nearing the end of the timeline, will decrease proportionally to 100px

Comment: Working on the solution now. Need to use Math.abs() if you're impatient.

Comment: dude, thank you. I'm waiting anxiously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some `Math`, baby! Specifically, the `abs` function can be used to work out how far from the mid-point you are. Use the following to work out the **distance** from the centreline:

```
var timelineWidth = $('#timeline').width;
var dist = Maths.abs((width/2) - e.ClientX); // distance from the middle
```

Your final function would then look something like this:

```
$('#timeline').mousemove(function(e){
    var timelineWidth = $('#timeline').width();
    var position = e.clientX;
    /* Calculate the distance from the mid-point */
    var dist = Math.abs((position - 50) - timelineWidth/2);
    /* Work out the percentage increase needed for your square */
    var squareSide = ((timelineWidth-dist)/timelineWidth) * 200;
    $('#mark').css("left", position - 50);
    /* Apply the transformation to your square */
    $('#animation').height(squareSide);
    $('#animation').width(squareSide);
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: PS: I didn't use the `animate` function because then the transformation would lag behind the user input. If you still want to use animation though it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: dude, thak you very much. greetings from brazil